# Does SqlServerCe require additional libraries for simple home pc user?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I was wondering if SqlServerCe namespace require any additional libraries for home user. Or he has to install something in addition to make application with SqlServerCe database work?

Is the alternative to SqlServerCe that does not need any additional libraries that does not come with framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlServer CE is an in-process DB engine, you link all required DLLs with your application. When a home PC user installs your app, the required DLLs are included in your installer. There is no "additional" install.

Comment: Also note you only need to include SQL CE DLLs you actually use. For example, if you don't use database replication you don't need to include SQL CE Client Agent.

Comment: .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 or 4.0 is required, but otherwise nothing.